# Slow Startup with Ionic

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I'm trying out the ionic framework and am finding the application is loading very slowly with the basic tabs app (almost no changes).

Here's what I did:

```
ionic start TabsDemo tabs
cd \TabsDemo
ionic platform add android
ionic build TabsDemo
```

I commented out the two splash screen elements in the configuration. Running this on an HTC M7, I see a black screen for ~3 seconds before the application loads up the first time. After that resources are cached and the app loads fine.

Is there a setting or something I can do to get my app to load up in a reasonable amount of time or do all ionic apps suffer from this?

Comment: I have started using ionic recently and I am facing exactly the same issue

Comment: I started looking through the source of the generated app code, they have a lot going on. Wasn't sure if maybe I could tweak something. I will eventually get back to this, haven't had time yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add production flag and cut startup time using --release when you are in development stage it may be slow. Try bundling using gulp or grunt all your css and js.

I have tried out bundled apps with other devices. It works fine on multiple brands which we use for testing while developing those apps.

Ionic apps tested on:

- Karbon
- micromax
- nexus
- moto-e
- ipad
- iphone

Comment: Yes, it does work, but I'm talking about the initial loading speed. Is it instantaneous on others and only slow for my M7?

Comment: It depends on device also :)

Comment: Even for boilerplate app? I imagine it will get a lot slower when I add stuff. I really don't feel that my device isn't that under-powered. : /

Comment: Since I haven't received any follow ups and found similar claims for this type of tech, I will mark this as the answer considering getting bigger/better hardware is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

That black screen and white sheet with Ionic's symbol are the Splash Screen. Splash Screens are used to load block the UI and let the App finish it's background tasks on startup.

Comment: I get the purpose of a splash screen, I'm just saying it's slow. Is there a way to skip it or better disable it than the way I did?

Comment: Seeing the same thing. For native app,  the ui shows up in less than a second if not instantly.  Guess the webview will need time to load and parse the js and html then render the ui. Guess it's given.

Answer (score 0):

Use Crosswalk Webview Plugin. This not only provides you the great webview capabilities where your native webview lacks the performance but also it is providing feature constancy across Android 4.0+ Platforms. Only downside is it will increase the size of your build.

https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Comment: There's an easier way to do it using the CLI: http://blog.ionic.io/crosswalk-comes-to-ionic/